# R.Net Displaying list of objects returned by R code in an MVC application

Tags: asp.net, r, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-5.2, r.net

I have an R code which returns a list of numbers using

```
output <- return(list(add,diff,prod,div))
```

I need to display these results in an MVC application using R.Net. I am able to display this in case of console application, but not in MVC. The application is failing to display the result, creating the following error:Failed to load resource:  ***the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)***. Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my following controller code:

```
        public JsonResult OperatoR(int Text1, int Text2)
        {
        REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
        REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();

        var v = engine.CreateInteger(Text1);
        var u = engine.CreateInteger(Text2);

        engine.SetSymbol("u", u);
        engine.SetSymbol("v", v);

        engine.Evaluate("setwd(\"D:/Users/h224086/Desktop\")");
        engine.Evaluate("file<-dget(\"operators.r\")");
        engine.Evaluate("exec<-file(u,v)");
        var sum = engine.Evaluate("exec").AsIntegerMatrix();

        return Json(sum, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. You need to modify

```
var sum = engine.Evaluate("exec").AsIntegerMatrix();
```

as

```
 IntegerVector group1 = engine.Evaluate("exec").AsInteger();               
 engine.SetSymbol("group1", group1);
```